# Data modeling for employee has multiple managers

Tags: oracle, database-design

I've referred this [link](http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=recursive.php) for modelling the table for employee-manager relationship. However, in my use case, an employer can have multiple managers. I am wondering what would be the best solution for this. Any suggestions for modelling this use case?

Comment: So which is it?  An employee can have multiple mangers?  Or an employer can have multiple managers?

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a many to many relationship where you need a **bridge table**. You would store everyone in an employee table with an ID and then have a separate hierarchy table with manager and employee combinations.

Comment: No, it is not a many to many relationship. One employee can have one manager or many managers. In other side, a manager can be an employee only.

Comment: That is a 0:n relationship which falls under many to many.

Comment: Wait a minute.Can a manager manage more than one employee?  If yes, and given what you've already said, then it is a many to many relation ship.

Comment: @WalterMitty Assume that one manager can manage only one employee? In that case, what is the relationship and how would you model it ? Kindly provide the table structure if possible (with minimum fields example: with name field only). It will be easy for me to understand.

Comment: I am sorry.  I misread the op.  "an employer can have multiple managers".  I misread that as employee.  I'll let somebody else sort this one out.

Comment: Are you saying an employee can have many managers but a manager can only manage one employee? That arrangement won't work for mathematical reasons - you'll exhaust your manager supply.

Comment: Agreed. Please just assume that is the case. My entity names are different. I have just simplified the names employee and manager.

Comment: If that is true, then your data model is very simple. You just need a foreign key from the manager to the employee as "managed_employee_id" or something like that.

Comment: It's confusing because above you use both "employee" and "employer" which are not the same thing.  In any event, if the employee can have multiple managers and the manager can have only one employee then @CalZ is correct that your manager record will just need to store a foreign key to the employee.